# Closure of $\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \ \text{x is rational}\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I want to find the closure of $$\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \ \text{x is rational}\}$$

My ATTEMPT:

Let $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be any point and $r>0$. Let   $q \in (x-r, x+r) \cap \mathbb{Q}$, then $(q,y) \in B_d((x,y),r) \cap D$. Hence, $(x,y) \in \overline{D}$, which proves that $\overline{D} = \mathbb{R}^2$.

Please check my solution. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good! I would just add one more sentence mentioning why we know that $q$ exist, in other words, why we know that $(x-r, x+r)\cap \mathbb Q$ is non-empty.

Note, we know that because we know that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

---

An equivalent alternative proof would be to find a sequence $\{q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ that converges to $x$, then show that the sequence $\{(q_n, y)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $(x,y)$.

Just like in your proof, the existence of the sequence  $\{q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is guaranteed by the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. I would mention that "$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$".